# bootstrap collapse panel giving strange output in angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-forms

I just want simple collapse panel for search filter in angular2.
It is pretty simple.but i am not getting what I am missing here...
It haven't show panel body  on button click but glyphicon changes its behaviour.
I have set boolean value in code behind so that on click of search button that inside panel body,results in collapse too.
Please correct me where I am going wrong... 
thanq in advanced

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <!--<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
            Collapsible panel</a>-->
            <button type="button" class="glyphicon"
                    [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': isCollapsedContent , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !isCollapsedContent }"
                    style="float: right;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1"
                    (click)="isCollapsedContent = !isCollapsedContent"></button>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using as below

```
<div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">Simple collapsible</button>
      </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
         <div id="collapse1" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jueTNIIpG1eufqI0RWIV?p=preview)**

Comment: your content should be wrapped inside panel body, instead you are wrapping the panel body inside your collapse which is wrong

Comment: @user19041992 so my answer is helpful or need more help?

Comment: Did u see the live demo